# Proof ownership of private key for blinded public key

Tags: public-key, signature, blind-signature

so i want to prove to a server that i have the private key to  a public key for which i want to retrieve the server's signature. But the server is not allowed to learn either public nor private key.

In more detail:
In my setup a client has both public key *pk* and private key *sk*. For some authentication we need the server's signature over *pk*. The protocol is as follows:

1. The client creates a  blinded message by blinding *pk*.
2. It then sends this message to the server.
3. The server signs the message and sends it back.
4. The client can unblind the message and derive the signature for *pk*.

To mitigate one specific kind of impersonation attack it is important, that the client can only retrieve the signature for a  public key for which it also has the secret key.

We first thought that the server could send a challenge, the clients signs and blinds it and the server uses the blinded public key it received earlier to verify the challenge. 
But this does not work because blinding requires padding and hashing.

Does anyone has an approach they can point me to?

Comment: You mention keys but are treating them as the message to be signed since they are not part of any cryptographic operations. Once you reword this, it sounds like you want to authenticate with the server to obtain blind signatures. This can be done any number of ways and has little to do with the message itself. Can you rephrase your question with that in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hope it more clear now..

Comment: This does not address my comment. With the restrictions you mentioned (server cannot know the public key of the client) this is just signing a random message. You need to use some sort of authentication (be it key pairs or other) for the server to identify the client.

Comment: The server does uses a token that is provided by the client to ensure that the client is allowed to retrieve a signature. The token is given to the client trough another channel, which is not important for the question.